# Keycloak Create Client

Tags: java, jboss, keycloak, keycloak-services

I'm trying to create a new Keycloak client using the `keycloak-admin-client`.

Here's my code:

```java
        Keycloak keycloak =
                KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                        .serverUrl("http://localhost:8080/auth")
                        .realm("realm-name")
                        .grantType(OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD)
                        .username("admin")
                        .password("adminPassword")
                        .clientId("admin-cli")
                        .resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilderImpl().connectionPoolSize(10).build())
                        .build();

        ClientRepresentation clientRep = new ClientRepresentation();
        clientRep.setClientId(clientId);
        clientRep.setSecret(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        clientRep.setProtocol("openid-connect");

        keycloak.realm("realm-name").clients().create("test-client");
```

When doing this, I get an unauthorized error (`javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized`), but I know my admin password is correct.

My use case is that I am using the main Keycloak admin. I need to be able to set up a realm, client, and user (and then some configurations) using only the client API and without any manual steps. I'm needing to set up a completely automated Keycloak setup for the sake of a Dockerized CI/CD build.

It's worth noting that I'm not needing this to be the *most* secure strategy. I'm just wanting to write some code that I can use to automate setting up a Dockerize Keycloak instance for some tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this part:

```
Keycloak keycloak =
                KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                        .serverUrl("http://localhost:8080/auth")
                        .realm("realm-name")
                        .grantType(OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD)
                        .username("admin")
                        .password("adminPassword")
                        .clientId("admin-cli")
                        .resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilderImpl().connectionPoolSize(10).build())
                        .build();
```

instead of `.realm("realm-name")` use `.realm("master")`

Comment: Care to share why using "master" realm solves the issue? We are not using "master" and it works as expected. What other Keycloak settings/config are related to the change in realm?

Comment: @user1653042 it works with master because the admin of the master realm has full rights. It this should also work with other users that have at least the permission to create clients